# What do I need to reset to get clone and heal to not be prohibited?

Tags: gimp

I just downloaded Gimp, opened a few photos, and clone, heal, and perspective clone are prohibited (the little "no" circle). All other tools work. I read that I need to make sure two things are unlocked, but I can't find how to find out where they are, and the supposed answer I found had opened layers and brushes, but my layers tab doesn't have brushes.

Could someone please tell me what tab, option, etc to click to reset it appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a source first in order to use these tools. To do so, hold down CTRL+click on the image to set the source.

When using these tools, you can choose different brushes in the Tool Options panel, directly under the toolbox, or from the Brushes panel (Shift+Ctrl+B).

More info is available in GIMP's user documentation for the [Clone tool here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-clone.html) and [Heal tool here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-heal.html)